# enviar mail en formulario de contacto

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp

Mi problema es el siguiente, tengo un formulario de contacto en mi pagina, cada vez que quiero mandar un correo a mi casilla me tira un error.
Dejo mi código para ver si en realidad esta mal.

Lo que quiero lograr es poner la dirección de correo de la persona que quiera contactarme y que me lo envíe con el cuerpo del mensaje que haya escrito esa persona

Desde ya muchas gracias.

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {
            MailMessage msj = new MailMessage();
            msj.From = new MailAddress(txtEmail.Text);
            msj.To.Add("mi casilla de correo");
            msj.Subject = txtName.Text;
            msj.Body = txtMensaje.Text;

            SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("smtp.live.com");
            sc.Port = 25;
            sc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("mi casilla de corre", "Mi contraseña");

            sc.EnableSsl = true;
            sc.Send(msj);
            Response.Write("Correo Enviado");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Response.Write(ex.Message);
        }


    }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Cuál es el error que recibes al intentar enviar el correo?

Comment: Difícilmente el servidor de correo te va a dejar enviar un correo desde tu cuenta, si pones como remitente una cuenta de correo que no es tuya. Lo que usualmente se hace es poner como remitente tu propia cuenta de correo y utilizar un header `REPLY-TO` para que puedas luego darle _responder_ a ese correo y la respuesta vaya a la dirección de la persona que te envió el mensaje.

Answer (score 2):

Un servidor de correo usualmente no te permitirá enviar un correo desde una cuenta A, si el mensaje tiene como remitente una dirección de correo que no pertenece a dicha cuenta, menos si es de otro dominio.

Por lo que interpreto que quieres funcionar, te recomiendo construir el correo poniendo como remitente tu propia cuenta, y agregar un header `reply-to`, de manera que luego puedas darle *responder* en cualquier cliente de correo y la respuesta vaya dirigida a la dirección que te dejaron en el formulario de contacto.

Algo en la línea de:

```
protected void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage msj = new MailMessage();
        msj.From = new MailAddress("micuenta@midominio.com");
        msg.ReplyToList.Add(txtEmail.Text);
        msj.To.Add("miotracuenta@midominio.com");
        msj.Subject = txtName.Text;
        msj.Body = txtMensaje.Text;

        SmtpClient sc = new SmtpClient("smtp.midominio.com");
        sc.Port = 25;
        sc.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("micuenta@midominio.com", "****");

        sc.EnableSsl = true;
        sc.Send(msj);
        Response.Write("Correo Enviado");

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex.Message);
    }
}
```